# static_assert on array values

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, static-assert

Is it possible to have a compile-time check on array values?

example:

```
typedef enum
{
    dummy0 = 0,
    dummy1,
    dummy2
} eDummyEnum;

typedef struct
{
    eDummyEnum name;
    int value;
} sDummyStruct;

const sDummyStruct array[]=
{
    {dummy0, 3},
    {dummy1, 5},
    {dummy2, 6}
}
```

Is there any possibility to check if `array[dummy1].name == dummy1` at compilation time?

Comment: You don't need to check it. You wrote it right there in the initialising code.

Comment: array is big, and there is a chance to write    
    {dummy0, 3},
    {dummy2, 5},
    {dummy1, 6}

Comment: thus reversing the names in initialization

Comment: There's precisely the same chance you'll make that mistake in the assertions. This level of testing is totally useless!

Comment: Deleted answer the question as stated, does not accurately state what the OP is looking for.

Comment: no, because what i want to test is that the array initialization is in the same order as the enum

Comment: So you went from having two lists to get right... to having three lists to get right. Pointless.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Absolute nonsense.  If there's a 10% chance of error in one list, then having two lists drops the chance of error down to 1%.  This is exactly why we have automated tests.

Comment: If I cannot find a way to avoid such self-repeating code, I prefer to generate it with a small script. It will be easier to maintain that way.

Comment: @MooingDuck: In general perhaps, but not in this form. It's such a thin translation of the original logic that I don't see much value in it. I'm just waiting for the next question to be "how do I automatically convert the array initialisation into a sequence of `static_assert`s?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
constexpr sDummyStruct array[]=
{
    {dummy0, 3},
    {dummy1, 5},
    {dummy2, 6}
};

constexpr bool checkArray(int index) {
    return (index >= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])) ||
           (array[index].name == index && checkArray(index + 1));          
}

static_assert(checkArray(0), "bad array");
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/KTIAQ56769)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this could be made a bit more efficient but I think the following code does work correctly:

```
template <typename T, int N>
constexpr int size(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

template <int I, int J>
struct check_name {
    static constexpr bool check() {
        return array[I].name != array[J].name
            && check_name<I + 1, J>::check()
            && check_name<I, J - 1>::check();
    }
};

template <int I>
struct check_name<I, I> {
    static constexpr bool check() { return true; }
};
constexpr bool check_names() {
    return check_name<0, size(array) - 1>::check();
}

static_assert(check_names(), "duplicate names");
```

Comment: it does work correctly but as far as i've seen it doesn't check the order of the initialization list, only duplicate names, but thanks